# Method call from prototype self executing method

Tags: javascript, prototype, self-executing-function

I'm trying to really get how prototype works in js. I'm currently on a little game project that is based on a loop.

I would like to have a Game object instance that will start itself once instantiated, calling a loop method it defines.

What I'm trying to get is something like this :

```
function Game() {};
Game.prototype = {
    start: (function() {
        this.loop();    // this is where i have a problem
    })()

    loop: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, obviously, this doesn't work since I'm using a self executing function around start to get it launched automatically, so the 'this' keyword represents the window object, instead of the Game object.

Is there any way to do this so that I don't have to manually call the start method after I instantiated a new Game object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Game() { this.loop(); };
Game.prototype={ 

    loop: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

new Game;
```

Comment: Ok, that was what I came up with. But it kind of bothered me as I thought it might not be a good way to write code. I guess it must not be that bad after all. Thanks. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is the right way to write code , what did you expect ?

Comment: I don't know. I guess it's the fact that we first declare an object that must call a method loop that is not even yet defined in the same instruction block.

Comment: it is a function , thus it is not executed until it is called. Javascript interpreter will look up the prototype chain for a loop member until it finds it ( or not ). this / prototype is a bit complex to understand at first , since the this keyword has nothing to do with the java this .